# Getting video height and width via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, puppeteer, metadata

I'm looking for a way to get video width and height by Node.js (all I have is the video URL).

For that matter, I'm also using Puppeteer for getting video URLs from the web, so any manipulation needed that requires DOM is pretty much optionally doable - on the data crawling process I have access to the element.

Any suggestions for that issue?

CODE:

```js
export async function _getSourcesLinks(targetUrl: string): Promise < string[] > {
  return await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
    headless: true,
  }).then(async browser => {
    try {
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

      await page.goto(targetUrl, {
        waitUntil: 'load'
      })


      try {
        // waiting for video to appear
        await page.waitForTimeout(1500)
        // await page.waitForSelector('video', { timeout: 2500 }) // die after 2.5 seconds
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }

      const srcs = await page.$$eval < Element > ('video, .video, [src]', (videos) => {
        // TODO get also width and height
        return videos.map(video => {
          // @ts-ignore
          return video.getAttribute('src')
        })
      }) as never as string[]

      const downloadTargets = srcs.filter(src => {
        console.log(src)
        if (!src) return false
        const fitPattern = new RegExp('.*\.mp4.*')
        return fitPattern.test(src)
      })

      browser.close()
      return downloadTargets

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  })
}
```

As for the test video - I don't have one, it's just happened from time to time

Comment: Post the urls and your current puppeteer code.